# just a very simple example, but it cannot be compiled and generate PDF

Tags: xetex

e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Small is beautiful.
\end{document}
```

Command Line:

```
texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=1 "C:\Users\wendy\Desktop\cc.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\wendy\Desktop

pdflatex: try `pdflatex --help' for more information.
pdflatex: unrecognized option `--synctex=1'
texify: pdflatex.exe exited with bad status, quitting.
texify: see "cc.log" for errors.

_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! your document example works fine. which editor you use? can you start compilation from it?

Comment: Don't use texify (or pdftexify) if you get errors. It is difficult to debug. Run pdflatex directly.

Comment: I use Ctex  2..9.2.164_Full, the compiler environment is the default. And I tried pdflatex, but it had the same wrong.